# Open a text file scrolled at the end from vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want, at the end of my program, to open a sort of log of what happened during runtime, and logs being appended at the end, I want this file to be opened directly at the end.

I am using `Process.Start(output)` for the moment, and I know this function can take an extra command line argument. Is there any argument that could make the file open at the bottom? 
Or any other means to do so?

Thank you

Comment: The command line arguments depend on what *command* you're executing.  Which is what?  What application are you opening, and when you look up the documentation for that application what command line arguments are available?

Comment: Im opening a regular text file through whatever the default reader is, im not specifying any specific application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `SendKeys` method, you can make it even more complex by using `Windows` API to find the `Notepad` windows and then use the `SendKeys` method, but this should do it :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim P As Process = New Process()
    Dim PSI As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo() With {
        .FileName = "C:\Users\VM\text.txt"
    }
    P.StartInfo = PSI
    P.Start()
    P.WaitForInputIdle()
    SendKeys.SendWait("^{END}")
End Sub
```

**Hope it will help you :)**